# getting JavaScript to execute multiple if statements

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement

How do I get the below JavaScript code to execute multiple if statements regardless of the if statement above being true or false.

here is the code

```
var uname = document.getElementById("pword1").value;
    var pword = document.getElementById("cPassword").value;
    var passReq = "^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[\\\+\=\"\.\[\]_£|`¬':;~{}<>()#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,20}$";

    var matchCol = "#009900";
    var noMatchCol = "#CC0000";
    var noBg = "#FFFFFF";


    if (uname.length < 1 || pword.length < 1){
        cPassword.style.backgroundColor = noBg;
        match = "";
    }else if(passReq.test(uname)){
        DIMR = "Does Meet Requirements";
    }else if(!passReq.test(uname)){
        DIMR = "Does Not Meet Requirements";
    }else if (pword1.value == cPassword.value){
        match = "Match!";
        cPassword.style.backgroundColor = matchCol;
    } else if  (pword1.value != cPassword.value){
        match = "No Match!";
        cPassword.style.backgroundColor = noMatchCol;
    }
    document.getElementById("combination").innerHTML = match;
    document.getElementById("reqMeeting").innerHTML = DIMR;
}
```

I have 2 input boxes. "Password" and "Confirm Password". I want various to happen including: if nothing is entered no messages are returned, if the passwords don't match then the confirm password turns red, if they do match turns green, if the value does not fit the regular expression then send another message to the screen saying "does not meet requirements, if it does match expression then send a different messsage to the screen saying "does meet requirements".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want it to be more like:

```
var uname = document.getElementById("pword1").value;
    var pword = document.getElementById("cPassword").value;
    var passReq = "^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[\\\+\=\"\.\[\]_£|`¬':;~{}<>()#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,20}$";
    var pwReqExp = new RegExp(passReq);

    var matchCol = "#009900";
    var noMatchCol = "#CC0000";
    var noBg = "#FFFFFF";


    if (uname.length < 1 || pword.length < 1){
        cPassword.style.backgroundColor = noBg;
        match = "";
    }

    if(pwReqExp.test(uname)){
        DIMR = "Does Meet Requirements";
    }else {
        DIMR = "Does Not Meet Requirements";
    }

    if (pword1.value == cPassword.value){
        match = "Match!";
        cPassword.style.backgroundColor = matchCol;
    } else {
        match = "No Match!";
        cPassword.style.backgroundColor = noMatchCol;
    }
    document.getElementById("combination").innerHTML = match;
    document.getElementById("reqMeeting").innerHTML = DIMR;
}
```

update:
added new RegExp

```
var pwReqExp = new RegExp(passReq);
// ...
pwReqExp.test(uname)
// ...
```

Comment: this is what confuses me. your answer seems correct. i walk through it and it seems like it should return results I want. yet when i refresh my page and type in various things to test it, nothing is happening. no green/red box. and JavaScript has no help function

Comment: OR rather, how do you say if something matches a regular expression?

Comment: @BlueShark it has a console though and you should be going step by step and testing to see at what point the issue lies..

Answer (score 0):

Javascript, like java evaluates `if` statements and "links" them to the previous one, so you should end the `if` and use this syntax:

```
if (expression) {
//code goes here
}
else {}

if (other expression) {
//more code
} else {}

if (yet another expression) {
//even more code
} else {}
```

Comment: the solution I found was similar to this but involved the else{} statement after the first if to remain open and allow and if inside so essentially it was if this do this else do this if

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying... any grammar?

Comment: lol sorry. your solution was nearly right but for the first if(expression){ } else{}. instead of closing the else I kept it open like so else{. meaning that the other if statements were within the else statement rather than separate statements

Comment: He said "to execute **multiple** if statements **regardless** of the if statement above being true or false."